# Save for web photoshop looks fine in all browsers apart from IE10

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-10, photoshop

I made a webpage with photoshop, sliced it & saved for web. It looks fine in Chrome, Firefox, Opera & Safari, but when you view it in IE 10 it goes all weird... Does anyone know of a fix for this?

IE 10:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsiIX.jpg

Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Opera:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7dVq.jpg

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"                    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<title>Online Support</title>
<style type="text/css">
div {
  height: 400px;
  width: 592px;
  background: #ffffff;
  margin: auto;
}

p {
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  font: 14px/1.5 Helvetica, sans-serif;
}}
.auto-style3 {
    border-width: 0px;
}
</style>

</head>

<body style="margin: 0; background-image: url('images/About%20Us%20Background.jpg')">

<div id="position">
<table id="Table_01" width="593" height="763" border="0" cellpadding="0"     cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="11">
            <img src="images/Online-Support_01.gif" width="592" height="89"     alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="89" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="3">
        <a href="Index.html">
        <img src="images/Online-Support_02.gif" width="88" height="46"     alt="" class="auto-style3"></a></td>
    <td rowspan="3">
        <a href="About%20Us.html">
        <img src="images/Online-Support_03.gif" width="80" height="46"     alt="" class="auto-style3"></a></td>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="3">
        <a href="Online%20Support.html">
        <img src="images/Online-Support_04.gif" width="128" height="46" alt="" class="auto-style3"></a></td>
    <td rowspan="3">
        <a href="Testimonials.html">
        <img src="images/Online-Support_05.gif" width="106" height="46" alt="" class="auto-style3"></a></td>
    <td rowspan="3">
        <a href="Contact%20%20Us.html">
        <img src="images/Online-Support_06.gif" width="95" height="46" alt="" class="auto-style3"></a></td>
    <td colspan="4">
        <img src="images/Online-Support_07.gif" width="95" height="7" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="7" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="7">
        <img src="images/Online-Support_08.gif" width="18" height="666" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Always-Connected-Ltd/373671419315390">
        <img src="images/Online-Support_09.gif" width="33" height="33" alt="" class="auto-style3"></a></td>
    <td>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/Always_Connect">
        <img src="images/Online-Support_10.gif" width="33" height="33" alt="" class="auto-style3"></a></td>
    <td rowspan="7">
        <img src="images/Online-Support_11.gif" width="11" height="666" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="33" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="6">
        <img src="images/Online-Support_12.gif" width="66" height="633" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="6" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="7">
        <img src="images/Online-Support_13.gif" width="497" height="206" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="206" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="4">
        <img src="images/Online-Support_14.gif" width="12" height="421" alt=""></td>
    <td colspan="3">
        <a href="http://www.teamviewer.com/link/?url=505374&amp;amp;id=1585160200">
        <img src="images/Online-Support_15.gif" width="200" height="125" alt="" class="auto-style3"></a></td>
    <td colspan="3" rowspan="4">
        <img src="images/Online-Support_16.gif" width="285" height="421" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="125" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">
        <img src="images/Online-Support_17.gif" width="200" height="17" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="17" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">
        <a href="http://download.teamviewer.com/download/TeamViewer.dmg">
        <img src="images/Online-Support_18.gif" width="200" height="125" alt="" class="auto-style3"></a></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="125" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">
        <img src="images/Online-Support_19.gif" width="200" height="154" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="154" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="12" height="1" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="76" height="1" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="80" height="1" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="44" height="1" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="84" height="1" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="106" height="1" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="95" height="1" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="18" height="1" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="33" height="1" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="33" height="1" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="11" height="1" alt=""></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</table>

</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yuck. Yucky yuck yuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to set `<a>` or `<img>` border none, use this code:

```
a, img{
    border:none;
}
```

<sub>I don't have IE10 for test</sub>

Answer (score 0):

you need to add

```
img {border:0; ouline:0; padding:0; margin:0}
```